# Why is my Vim startup dominated by "first screen update"?

Tags: startup

I'm trying to investigate why Vim startup is pretty slow. `vim -u NONE` and the like are extremely fast as expected, so it is obviously my `config/plugins`, but what strikes me, is that most of the time is spent on `first screen update`.

Some stats:

Using `:Startuptime` from `vim-startuptime`

```
       startup: 1854.2
event                  time percent plot
first screen update  1505.1   81.17 ██████████████████████████
vimrc                 85.49    4.61 █▌
opening buffers       78.69    4.24 █▍
filetype.vim          39.89    2.15 ▊
```

Raw output of `vim --startup`:

```
924.078  000.482  000.482: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tagbar/autoload/tagbar/types/uctags.vim
924.279  000.041  000.041: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tagbar/autoload/tagbar/prototypes/typeinfo.vim
1595.653  1251.840: first screen update
1595.660  000.007: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

Compared to the 1-3 ms needed for `vim -u NONE` to update the first screen this is extremely slow and also very uninformative about the actual root cause.

Is there a better way to know what is happening during `first screen update` which makes it so slow other than disabling plugins one-by-one? If there isn't, can I get a list of what things happen during this first screen update if it is not the loading of plugins?

## Edit:

### Full logs:

`vim --startup`:

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.010  000.010: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.139  000.129: Allocated generic buffers
000.312  000.173: locale set
000.318  000.006: GUI prepared
000.319  000.001: clipboard setup
000.321  000.002: window checked
000.789  000.468: inits 1
000.884  000.095: parsing arguments
000.885  000.001: expanding arguments
000.895  000.010: shell init
001.259  000.364: Termcap init
001.286  000.027: inits 2
001.369  000.083: init highlight
001.586  000.152  000.152: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/debian.vim
004.215  002.412  002.412: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/colors/lists/default.vim
004.338  002.633  000.221: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/syncolor.vim
004.436  002.770  000.137: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/synload.vim
009.945  005.470  005.470: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/filetype.vim
010.275  000.138  000.138: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/autoload/dist/script.vim
010.662  000.563  000.425: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/scripts.vim
010.702  009.078  000.275: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/syntax.vim
010.718  009.330  000.100: sourcing $VIM/vimrc
016.914  001.886  001.886: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/autoload/plug.vim
017.416  000.184  000.184: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/ale.vim
017.861  000.433  000.433: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/coc.vim
017.949  000.076  000.076: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/floaterm.vim
018.218  000.260  000.260: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/fzf.vim
019.150  000.924  000.924: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/git.vim
019.353  000.193  000.193: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/goyo.vim
019.477  000.113  000.113: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/i3wm-kitty-vim-tmux-navigator.vim
019.686  000.199  000.199: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/iamcco-markdown-preview.vim
019.911  000.214  000.214: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/movements.vim
023.453  003.531  003.531: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/plugins.vim
023.641  000.175  000.175: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/tags.vim
024.246  000.593  000.593: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/theme-setup.vim
024.422  000.164  000.164: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/vim-auto-save.vim
024.509  000.076  000.076: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/vim-easy-align.vim
024.586  000.068  000.068: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/vim-obsession.vim
024.661  000.067  000.067: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/vim-polyglot.vim
024.761  000.093  000.093: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/vim-swap.vim
025.024  000.256  000.256: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/vimspector.vim
025.920  000.887  000.887: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/vim-plug-configs/writing.vim
026.992  000.975  000.975: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/ftoff.vim
031.530  000.005  000.005: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-polyglot/filetype.vim
035.722  000.015  000.015: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-fugitive/ftdetect/fugitive.vim
036.014  000.013  000.013: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-tmux-syntax/ftdetect/tmux-conf.vim
036.208  000.162  000.162: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-kitty/ftdetect/kitty.vim
036.441  000.012  000.012: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-javascript/ftdetect/flow.vim
036.494  000.042  000.042: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-javascript/ftdetect/javascript.vim
036.578  000.032  000.032: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-json/ftdetect/json.vim
036.660  000.006  000.006: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/mbsync.vim/ftdetect/mbsync.vim
036.761  000.014  000.014: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-polyglot/ftdetect/polyglot.vim
036.824  000.017  000.017: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimtex/ftdetect/cls.vim
036.858  000.023  000.023: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimtex/ftdetect/tex.vim
036.965  000.015  000.015: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimtex/ftdetect/tikz.vim
037.042  000.031  000.031: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-markdown/ftdetect/markdown.vim
037.261  005.679  005.297: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/filetype.vim
037.410  000.008  000.008: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-fugitive/ftdetect/fugitive.vim
037.558  000.007  000.007: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-tmux-syntax/ftdetect/tmux-conf.vim
037.705  000.131  000.131: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-kitty/ftdetect/kitty.vim
037.829  000.005  000.005: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-javascript/ftdetect/flow.vim
037.850  000.016  000.016: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-javascript/ftdetect/javascript.vim
037.884  000.014  000.014: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-json/ftdetect/json.vim
037.944  000.005  000.005: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/mbsync.vim/ftdetect/mbsync.vim
038.022  000.007  000.007: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-polyglot/ftdetect/polyglot.vim
038.067  000.011  000.011: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimtex/ftdetect/cls.vim
038.083  000.011  000.011: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimtex/ftdetect/tex.vim
038.095  000.008  000.008: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimtex/ftdetect/tikz.vim
038.138  000.022  000.022: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-markdown/ftdetect/markdown.vim
051.242  004.264  004.264: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-polyglot/extras/filetype.vim
052.651  021.599  011.406: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-polyglot/autoload/polyglot/init.vim
052.660  021.889  000.290: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-polyglot/filetype.vim
052.726  000.008  000.008: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/filetype.vim
053.070  000.034  000.034: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/ftplugin.vim
053.396  000.021  000.021: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/indent.vim
053.826  000.035  000.035: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/promptline.vim/autoload/promptline/slices.vim
054.093  000.010  000.010: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/promptline.vim/autoload/promptline/slices/cwd.vim
054.361  000.027  000.027: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/promptline.vim/autoload/promptline/symbols.vim
054.691  000.024  000.024: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/promptline.vim/autoload/promptline/slices/vcs_branch.vim
055.028  000.009  000.009: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/promptline.vim/autoload/promptline/slices/last_exit_code.vim
056.218  000.874  000.874: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/colors/lists/default.vim
056.973  000.103  000.103: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/syncolor.vim
057.428  000.091  000.091: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/syncolor.vim
057.779  000.067  000.067: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/dracula/autoload/dracula.vim
059.627  003.139  002.878: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/dracula/colors/dracula.vim
059.654  048.918  011.481: sourcing ~/.vim/vimrc
059.659  000.042: sourcing vimrc file(s)
059.910  000.088  000.088: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugin/hunmap.vim
059.963  000.046  000.046: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugin/mycommands.vim
060.338  000.369  000.369: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugin/settings.vim
060.959  000.071  000.071: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/events.vim
061.299  000.928  000.857: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/ale/plugin/ale.vim
061.533  000.108  000.108: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/autoload/coc/rpc.vim
061.815  000.214  000.214: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/autoload/coc/util.vim
062.082  000.144  000.144: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/autoload/coc/client.vim
063.759  000.397  000.397: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/autoload/coc/api.vim
064.579  003.248  002.385: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/plugin/coc.vim
064.687  000.050  000.050: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/coc-fzf/plugin/coc_fzf.vim
064.935  000.218  000.218: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-floaterm/plugin/floaterm.vim
065.696  000.660  000.660: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/fzf/plugin/fzf.vim
066.555  000.813  000.813: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/fzf.vim/plugin/fzf.vim
066.761  000.161  000.161: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/fzf-checkout.vim/plugin/fzf_checkout.vim
067.782  000.979  000.979: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-fugitive/plugin/fugitive.vim
067.898  000.067  000.067: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-fubitive/plugin/fubitive.vim
068.076  000.143  000.143: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/fugitive-gitlab.vim/plugin/gitlab.vim
068.252  000.144  000.144: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-rhubarb/plugin/rhubarb.vim
068.311  000.022  000.022: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/srht.vim/plugin/srht.vim
068.359  000.020  000.020: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-twiggy/plugin/twiggy.vim
068.494  000.097  000.097: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-flog/plugin/flog.vim
068.615  000.113  000.113: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-flog/plugin/flog_graph_vim.vim
068.958  000.126  000.126: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-gitgutter/autoload/gitgutter/utility.vim
069.260  000.093  000.093: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-gitgutter/autoload/gitgutter/highlight.vim
070.234  001.577  001.358: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-gitgutter/plugin/gitgutter.vim
070.309  000.017  000.017: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/goyo.vim/plugin/goyo.vim
070.597  000.255  000.255: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-tmux-navigator/plugin/tmux_navigator.vim
071.872  001.233  001.233: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-sneak/plugin/sneak.vim
072.754  000.825  000.825: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/quick-scope/plugin/quick_scope.vim
073.016  000.204  000.204: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-startuptime/plugin/startuptime.vim
074.400  001.345  001.345: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-dispatch/plugin/dispatch.vim
074.715  000.096  000.096: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-test/autoload/test.vim
075.712  001.267  001.171: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-test/plugin/test.vim
076.007  000.214  000.214: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-dadbod/plugin/dadbod.vim
076.307  000.261  000.261: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-dadbod-ui/plugin/db_ui.vim
076.465  000.116  000.116: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-dadbod-completion/plugin/vim_dadbod_completion.vim
076.901  000.401  000.401: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/diffchar.vim/plugin/diffchar.vim
077.593  000.168  000.168: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/matchparen.vim
078.736  000.192  000.192: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-matchup/autoload/matchup.vim
078.931  000.077  000.077: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-matchup/autoload/matchup/perf.vim
079.526  000.278  000.278: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-matchup/autoload/matchup/loader.vim
080.449  000.595  000.595: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-matchup/autoload/matchup/matchparen.vim
081.573  004.625  003.315: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-matchup/plugin/matchup.vim
081.837  000.212  000.212: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/targets.vim/plugin/targets.vim
082.617  000.572  000.572: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-textobj-user/autoload/textobj/user.vim
083.869  001.972  001.400: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-textobj-xmlattr/plugin/textobj/xmlattr.vim
084.087  000.160  000.160: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-heritage/plugin/heritage.vim
084.288  000.163  000.163: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-lastplace/plugin/vim-lastplace.vim
084.675  000.311  000.311: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-sandwich/plugin/operator/sandwich.vim
084.981  000.296  000.296: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-sandwich/plugin/sandwich.vim
085.132  000.141  000.141: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-sandwich/plugin/textobj/sandwich.vim
085.527  000.265  000.265: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-peekaboo/plugin/peekaboo.vim
086.318  000.748  000.748: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-abolish/plugin/abolish.vim
087.174  000.816  000.816: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-sleuth/plugin/sleuth.vim
087.763  000.554  000.554: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-speeddating/plugin/speeddating.vim
087.988  000.178  000.178: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-commentary/plugin/commentary.vim
088.350  000.309  000.309: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-vinegar/plugin/vinegar.vim
088.417  000.024  000.024: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets/plugin/vimsnippets.vim
088.611  000.163  000.163: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-slash/plugin/slash.vim
088.676  000.029  000.029: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/gundo.vim/plugin/gundo.vim
095.078  006.372  006.372: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-unimpaired/plugin/unimpaired.vim
095.768  000.631  000.631: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-eunuch/plugin/eunuch.vim
095.957  000.137  000.137: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/splitjoin.vim/plugin/splitjoin.vim
096.077  000.082  000.082: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/zoxide.vim/plugin/zoxide.vim
096.355  000.246  000.246: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-rooter/plugin/rooter.vim
096.415  000.021  000.021: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-backscratch/plugin/backscratch.vim
096.487  000.021  000.021: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/SimpylFold/plugin/SimpylFold.vim
096.721  000.198  000.198: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/jupyter_ascending.vim/plugin/jupyter_ascending.vim
097.001  000.247  000.247: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/jupytext.vim/plugin/jupytext.vim
097.590  000.545  000.545: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/FastFold/plugin/fastfold.vim
097.854  000.219  000.219: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/LargeFile/plugin/LargeFile.vim
098.156  000.254  000.254: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-gutentags/plugin/gutentags.vim
099.030  000.842  000.842: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tagbar/plugin/tagbar.vim
099.570  000.069  000.069: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/init.vim
100.374  000.370  000.370: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/parts.vim
100.756  000.008  000.008: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/formatter/short_path.vim
101.916  000.118  000.118: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/util.vim
102.001  002.917  002.352: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/plugin/airline.vim
102.078  000.028  000.028: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline-themes/plugin/airline-themes.vim
102.146  000.032  000.032: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/promptline.vim/plugin/promptline.vim
102.240  000.061  000.061: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tmuxline.vim/plugin/tmuxline.vim
103.116  000.123  000.123: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline.vim
104.232  001.958  001.835: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-devicons/plugin/webdevicons.vim
104.523  000.239  000.239: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-auto-save/plugin/AutoSave.vim
104.709  000.148  000.148: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-easy-align/plugin/easy_align.vim
104.917  000.172  000.172: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-obsession/plugin/obsession.vim
105.082  000.125  000.125: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-swap/plugin/swap.vim
105.920  000.803  000.803: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimspector/plugin/vimspector.vim
106.675  000.111  000.111: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimspectorpy/autoload/vimspectorpy.vim
106.748  000.777  000.666: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimspectorpy/plugin/vimspectorpy.vim
106.821  000.026  000.026: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimtex/plugin/vimtex.vim
107.107  000.230  000.230: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tabular/plugin/Tabular.vim
107.256  000.073  000.073: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/bibtexcite.vim/plugin/bibtexcite.vim
107.608  000.300  000.300: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/cetli.vim/plugin/cetli.vim
107.743  000.081  000.081: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/loremipsum/plugin/loremipsum.vim
108.916  000.647  000.647: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimwiki/autoload/vimwiki/vars.vim
110.374  000.184  000.184: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimwiki/autoload/vimwiki/u.vim
115.391  000.044  000.044: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimwiki/autoload/vimwiki/markdown_base.vim
115.951  002.444  002.400: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimwiki/autoload/vimwiki/base.vim
116.401  000.129  000.129: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimwiki/autoload/vimwiki/path.vim
121.280  013.498  010.094: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimwiki/plugin/vimwiki.vim
121.398  000.052  000.052: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-zettel/plugin/zettel.vim
121.544  000.084  000.084: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-polyglot/plugin/polyglot.vim
121.728  000.058  000.058: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
122.007  000.267  000.267: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/gzip.vim
122.195  000.168  000.168: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/logiPat.vim
122.234  000.022  000.022: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/manpager.vim
122.253  000.009  000.009: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/matchparen.vim
122.986  000.723  000.723: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
123.040  000.029  000.029: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/rrhelper.vim
123.076  000.020  000.020: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/spellfile.vim
123.298  000.207  000.207: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
123.406  000.090  000.090: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/tohtml.vim
123.634  000.216  000.216: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
123.892  000.232  000.232: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
123.901  003.935: loading plugins
123.976  000.075: loading packages
124.992  000.855  000.855: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/fzf.vim/autoload/fzf/vim.vim
125.332  001.257  000.402: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/coc-fzf/after/plugin/coc_fzf.vim
125.416  000.009  000.009: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-dadbod-completion/after/plugin/vim_dadbod_completion.vim
125.612  000.003  000.003: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-matchup/after/plugin/matchit.vim
125.841  000.145  000.145: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/dracula/after/plugin/dracula.vim
126.458  000.172  000.172: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tabular/autoload/tabular.vim
127.728  001.833  001.661: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tabular/after/plugin/TabularMaps.vim
128.609  000.818  000.818: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/after/plugin/maps.vim
128.612  000.571: loading after plugins
128.629  000.017: inits 3
129.729  001.100: reading viminfo
131.540  001.811: setup clipboard
131.569  000.029: setting raw mode
131.573  000.004: start termcap
131.612  000.039: clearing screen
132.752  000.127  000.127: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale.vim
133.688  000.066  000.066: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-matchup/autoload/matchup/re.vim
134.576  000.246  000.246: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions.vim
134.963  000.060  000.060: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/quickfix.vim
135.336  000.022  000.022: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/netrw.vim
135.706  000.030  000.030: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/fzf.vim
136.590  000.076  000.076: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/term.vim
136.991  000.066  000.066: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/hunks.vim
137.340  000.036  000.036: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tagbar.vim
137.894  000.159  000.159: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/branch.vim
138.291  000.038  000.038: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/fugitiveline.vim
138.729  000.062  000.062: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/ale.vim
139.374  000.030  000.030: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/coc.vim
139.785  000.077  000.077: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/whitespace.vim
140.271  000.046  000.046: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/po.vim
140.629  000.064  000.064: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/wordcount.vim
141.126  000.189  000.189: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tabline.vim
141.534  000.034  000.034: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tabline/autoshow.vim
142.068  000.073  000.073: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tabline/tabs.vim
142.594  000.108  000.108: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tabline/buffers.vim
143.061  000.025  000.025: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tmuxline.vim
143.388  000.013  000.013: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/gutentags.vim
143.712  000.017  000.017: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/keymap.vim
144.050  000.040  000.040: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/obsession.vim
144.759  000.408  000.408: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vimtex/autoload/vimtex.vim
145.208  000.159  000.159: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/vimtex.vim
145.791  000.052  000.052: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/searchcount.vim
148.549  000.048  000.048: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/section.vim
149.176  000.290  000.290: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/highlighter.vim
152.331  000.072  000.072: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes.vim
153.114  001.195  001.123: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/dracula/autoload/airline/themes/dracula.vim
157.293  000.823  000.823: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/dracula/autoload/airline/themes/dracula.vim
160.262  000.016  000.016: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tmuxline.vim/autoload/tmuxline/api.vim
160.608  000.090  000.090: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tmuxline.vim/autoload/tmuxline/util.vim
161.043  000.105  000.105: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tmuxline.vim/autoload/tmuxline.vim
161.380  000.014  000.014: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tmuxline.vim/autoload/tmuxline/presets/powerline.vim
161.697  000.053  000.053: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tmuxline.vim/autoload/tmuxline/builder.vim
174.318  000.198  000.198: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/builder.vim
175.134  000.064  000.064: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/default.vim
177.181  000.440  000.440: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-gitgutter/autoload/gitgutter/hunk.vim
180.812  000.526  000.526: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/engine.vim
181.015  000.092  000.092: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/statusline.vim
188.947  051.058: opening buffers
189.276  000.122  000.122: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-gitgutter/autoload/gitgutter.vim
190.127  000.134  000.134: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-peekaboo/autoload/peekaboo.vim
191.023  001.820: BufEnter autocommands
191.025  000.002: editing files in windows
192.100  000.365  000.365: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/autoload/coc/highlight.vim
192.570  000.402  000.402: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/autoload/coc/color.vim
200.234  000.357  000.357: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-gutentags/autoload/gutentags.vim
200.568  008.419: VimEnter autocommands
200.570  000.002: before starting main loop
200.733  000.121  000.121: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/cursor.vim
201.095  000.099  000.099: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-matchup/autoload/matchup/pos.vim
201.954  000.077  000.077: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tabline/ctrlspace.vim
202.346  000.067  000.067: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tabline/tabws.vim
203.484  000.175  000.175: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tabline/builder.vim
203.945  000.041  000.041: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tabline/buflist.vim
205.856  000.016  000.016: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-devicons/autoload/airline/extensions/tabline/formatters/webdevicons.vim
206.322  000.061  000.061: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tabline/formatters/default.vim
210.497  001.534  001.534: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tagbar/autoload/tagbar.vim
210.876  000.040  000.040: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tagbar/autoload/tagbar/debug.vim
521.208  000.276  000.276: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tagbar/autoload/tagbar/types/uctags.vim
521.514  000.025  000.025: sourcing /home/bferdinandy/.vim/plugged/tagbar/autoload/tagbar/prototypes/typeinfo.vim
892.096  688.994: first screen update
892.099  000.003: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

Comment: Prefer `vim --clean` to `vim -u NONE`.  And I donno how to find the root cause.  The source code doesn't break screen update process down, afa I see: http://github.com/vim/vim/blob/478668013f060a75b8cd8cc6ca2cf2abb3bcc4a5/src/main.c#L1498-L1504

Comment: Thanks for the link, it does look like this is as detailed as I'm going to get with reporting.

Comment: Not relevant, but I see some autoload files in your startuptime. That’s going to cost you when they could be run later (on-demand by the autoload mechanism). So maybe delay doing anything with Tagbar? It would be helpful to have the full startuptime report.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble They're going to be pretty long, should I edit them into the question?

Comment: @fbence yes, please [edit].

Comment: The full output of the startuptime plugin didn't fit inside, so I left it out. It got twice as fast since yesterday, although first screen update is still taking around 70% of the time.

Comment: I would try to find out why the `tagbar/debug.vim` is run. It seems to take 300 ms alone.

Comment: yeah, that "debug" also sounds fishy :)

Answer (score -1):

I would try [vim-startuptime](https://github.com/dstein64/vim-startuptime)

Once installed the `:StartupTime` command gives you an analysis of what takes time when Vim starts.

Here is an excerpt of the result for my configuration:

```
       startup: 1028.0
event                  time percent plot
_vimrc               206.00   20.04 ██████████████████████████
VimEnter autocommand 188.00   18.29 ████████████████████████
python_vimisort.vim  132.00   12.84 ████████████████▌
starting GUI         126.00   12.26 ████████████████
loading plugins       63.00    6.13 ████████
project.vim           58.00    5.64 ███████▌
path.vim              46.00    4.47 ██████
vimwiki.vim           33.00    3.21 ████
BufEnter autocommand  31.00    3.02 ████
lh-project.vim        26.00    2.53 ███
clap.vim              22.00    2.14 ███
filetype.vim          20.00    1.95 ██▌
filetype.vim          18.00    1.75 ██
nord.vim              17.00    1.65 ██
```

In particular it gives indications for every plugins helping you to find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that, I just messed up the name of the plugin, but the first report is from there. I'll update the question though.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I have been misled because I missed the `first screen update` event :-|